# Pregunta sobre eventos

Tags: javascript, eventos

Hola buenas como seria para que pueda o obtener el resultado creando un nuevo elemento y poniendo su precio, con esto solo puedo acceder al primero que todos los input que he creado con el boton azul usando querySelector, pero no va si uso querySelectorAll, no se como hacer que su correpsondiente precio y cantidad me devuelva el nuevo resultado con un keyup

```
var quantityInput = document.querySelector('#quantity');
```

```js
var buttonCalculate = document.getElementsByClassName('calculate')[0];
// var quantityInput = document.getElementById('quantity');
var quantityInput = document.querySelector('#quantity');
var quantity = document.getElementById('quantity').value;
var amount = Number(document.getElementsByTagName('span')[1].innerText.replace('$', ''));
var total = document.getElementsByTagName('span')[3];

//elements
var newItem = document.getElementById('new-item-create');
var row = document.querySelector('div.flex');
var dataset = Number(document.querySelector('div.flex').dataset.count);
var container = document.getElementsByClassName('container')[0];
// var data_count = container.getElementsByClassName('flex').length;


quantityInput.onkeyup = function(e){  
  total.innerText = e.target.value * amount;
};


//Create element
newItem.onclick = function(e, itemName, itemUnitPrice){
  
  //row flex
  var newRow = document.createElement('div');
  newRow.classList.add('flex'); newRow.setAttribute('data-count', dataset+=1); newRow.style.margin = '5px';
  
  //div name
  var newDivName = document.createElement('div'), newLabelName = document.createElement('input');
  newLabelName.setAttribute('placeholder', 'Name...');
  newDivName.appendChild(newLabelName); newRow.appendChild(newDivName);  
  
  ////div price
  var newDivPrice= document.createElement('div'), newLabelPrice = document.createElement('input');
  newDivPrice.appendChild(newLabelPrice); newRow.appendChild(newDivPrice); 
  newLabelPrice.style.width = '50px';
  
  //div quantity
  var newDivQuantity = document.createElement('div'), newLabel = document.createElement('label'), newInput = document.createElement('input') ;
  newDivQuantity.classList.add('quantity'); newLabel.innerText = 'QTY'; newInput.setAttribute('id', 'quantity');
  newLabel.appendChild(newInput); newDivQuantity.appendChild(newLabel); newRow.appendChild(newDivQuantity);  
  
  //span total
  var newSpanTotal = document.createElement('span'), newSpanHolder = document.createElement('span');
  newSpanTotal.classList.add('total');
  newSpanTotal.appendChild(newSpanHolder); newRow.appendChild(newSpanTotal);  
  
  //delete button
  var newDivButton = document.createElement('div'), newButton = document.createElement('button');
  newButton.classList.add('btn-delete', 'btn'); newButton.textContent = 'Delete';
  newDivButton.appendChild(newButton); newRow.appendChild(newDivButton);  
  
  container.appendChild(newRow);
};


window.onload = function(){
  document.getElementById('quantity').value = '';
};
```

```css
input {
  border: solid 1px black;
}

.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -ms-touch-action: manipulation;
  touch-action: manipulation;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  background-image: none;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.btn-success {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #5cb85c;
    border-color: #4cae4c;
    margin: 20px auto;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    width: 200px;
}

#new-item-create{
  color: #fff;
  background-color: blue;
  border-color: #4cae4c;
  margin: 20px auto;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  width: 200px;
}

.btn{
  border-radius: 3px;

}
.btn-delete {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #CF000F;
    border-color: #CF000F;
}

.quantity {
  margin: 0 5px;
}

.wrapper{
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}

.flex{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.flex2{
  display: flex;
  /* justify-content: space-around; */
  flex-flow: row-reverse wrap;
}

input{
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css">
  <title>Ironhack cart</title>
</head>
<body>
  
  <div class="wrapper">
    <h1>Ironhack merchandising shop</h1>
  </div>
  
  <div class="container">
    <div class="flex" data-count="0" style="margin:5px;">
      <div><span>Iron bubble head</span></div>
      <div><span>$25</span></div>
      <div class="quantity"><label for="">QTY <input id="quantity" type="text" value="0"></label></div>
      <span class="total" style="width:70px; height: 30px;"><span></span></span>
      <div><button class="btn btn-delete">Delete</button></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  
  <div class="flex2">
    <div id="new-item-create" class="btn">Create product</div>
    <div class="btn btn-success calculate">Calculate price</div>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: no te va tomar los otros por que se agregan despues , por lo tanto no  tomará los valores que ingrese despues  , porque segun jquery noi existen porque no se ejecutaron cuando se cargo el dom. , hice pruebas por eso te digo, mira copia el codigo artas veces , clona ese divl de clase .flex como 4 veces y lo pruebas.

Comment: si te creo jaja pero que solucion das? pero cuando creo un nuevo row se hace append al dom porque se ve pero entonces como hago?

Comment: eso es lo que estaba buscando, a mi tambien me pasa.

Comment: @franciscodwq ¿Te fue de utilidad la respuesta que te han dado?

Answer (score 0):

Te faltó crear el evento de cada nueva fila en la función *newItem*. Te pongo como quedaría:

```js
var quantityInput = document.querySelector('#quantity');
var buttonCalculate = document.getElementsByClassName('calculate')[0];
// var quantityInput = document.getElementById('quantity');
var quantityInput = document.querySelector('#quantity');
var quantity = document.getElementById('quantity').value;
var amount = Number(document.getElementsByTagName('span')[1].innerText.replace('$', ''));
var total = document.getElementsByTagName('span')[3];

//elements
var newItem = document.getElementById('new-item-create');
var row = document.querySelector('div.flex');
var dataset = Number(document.querySelector('div.flex').dataset.count);
var container = document.getElementsByClassName('container')[0];
// var data_count = container.getElementsByClassName('flex').length;


quantityInput.onkeyup = function(e){  
  total.innerText = e.target.value * amount;
};


//Create element
newItem.onclick = function(e, itemName, itemUnitPrice){

  //row flex
  var newRow = document.createElement('div');
  newRow.classList.add('flex'); newRow.setAttribute('data-count', dataset+=1); newRow.style.margin = '5px';

  //div name
  var newDivName = document.createElement('div'), newLabelName = document.createElement('input');
  newLabelName.setAttribute('placeholder', 'Name...');
  newDivName.appendChild(newLabelName); newRow.appendChild(newDivName);  

  ////div price
  var newDivPrice= document.createElement('div'), newLabelPrice = document.createElement('input');
  newDivPrice.appendChild(newLabelPrice); newRow.appendChild(newDivPrice); 
  newLabelPrice.style.width = '50px';

  //div quantity
  var newDivQuantity = document.createElement('div'), newLabel = document.createElement('label'), newInput = document.createElement('input') ;
  newDivQuantity.classList.add('quantity'); newLabel.innerText = 'QTY'; newInput.setAttribute('id', 'quantity');
  newLabel.appendChild(newInput); newDivQuantity.appendChild(newLabel); newRow.appendChild(newDivQuantity);  

  //span total
  var newSpanTotal = document.createElement('span'), newSpanHolder = document.createElement('span');
  newSpanTotal.classList.add('total');
  newSpanTotal.appendChild(newSpanHolder); newRow.appendChild(newSpanTotal);  

  //delete button
  var newDivButton = document.createElement('div'), newButton = document.createElement('button');
  newButton.classList.add('btn-delete', 'btn'); newButton.textContent = 'Delete';
  newDivButton.appendChild(newButton); newRow.appendChild(newDivButton);  

  container.appendChild(newRow);

  // Se crea evento para cada nuevo item
  newInput.onkeyup = function(e) {
    newSpanTotal.innerText = parseInt(e.target.value) * parseInt(newLabelPrice.value);
  }
};


window.onload = function(){
  document.getElementById('quantity').value = '';
};
```

```css
input {
  border: solid 1px black;
}

.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -ms-touch-action: manipulation;
  touch-action: manipulation;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  background-image: none;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.btn-success {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #5cb85c;
    border-color: #4cae4c;
    margin: 20px auto;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    width: 200px;
}

#new-item-create{
  color: #fff;
  background-color: blue;
  border-color: #4cae4c;
  margin: 20px auto;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  width: 200px;
}

.btn{
  border-radius: 3px;

}
.btn-delete {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #CF000F;
    border-color: #CF000F;
}

.quantity {
  margin: 0 5px;
}

.wrapper{
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}

.flex{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.flex2{
  display: flex;
  /* justify-content: space-around; */
  flex-flow: row-reverse wrap;
}

input{
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css">
  <title>Ironhack cart</title>
</head>
<body>
  
  <div class="wrapper">
    <h1>Ironhack merchandising shop</h1>
  </div>
  
  <div class="container">
    <div class="flex" data-count="0" style="margin:5px;">
      <div><span>Iron bubble head</span></div>
      <div><span>$25</span></div>
      <div class="quantity"><label for="">QTY <input id="quantity" type="text" value="0"></label></div>
      <span class="total" style="width:70px; height: 30px;"><span></span></span>
      <div><button class="btn btn-delete">Delete</button></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  
  <div class="flex2">
    <div id="new-item-create" class="btn">Create product</div>
    <div class="btn btn-success calculate">Calculate price</div>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```